scrapy - text and image downloading in one attempt
I have written code to scrape the text information and images from real estate website. I have set 1.5 seconds delay in order to guarantee that all information is scraped without any block. However, although the code works to scrape text information (room number, size and etc) in one attempt then goes to the next page after 1.5 seconds starts to scrape the same variables' information again, it works differently for images.
First, it scrapes the text information in the first real estate promotion listing in one attempt, then downloads the images one-by-one, by delaying 1.5 seconds. My challenge is to find the way to download the images in one attempt as it does in text information.
Please, help me to fix or adjust the code to download all images from the listing in one attempt.
I tried all the ways, got the help from chatgpt, but did not work as i want
Spider code
from ast import Try
import scrapy
from datetime import date
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from bookscraper.items import MenzillerItem
from bookscraper.itemloaders import MenzilProductLoader

class BinaspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "binaspider"
    allowed_domains = ["website is removed deliberately"]
    start_urls = ["website is removed deliberately"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("a.item_link::attr(href)"):
            ev_url = href.get()
            yield response.follow(ev_url, callback=self.parse_listing)

        for a in response.css('span.next a'):
            yield response.follow(a, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_listing(self, response):
        # Create an item loader instance
        loader = ItemLoader(item=MenzillerItem(), selector=response)

        # Scraping text information
        loader.add_css('elan_adi', 'h1.product-name::text')
        loader.add_css('elan_nomresi', 'div.product-actions__id::text')

        # Extract "Yeniləndi: Dünən 12:54"
        loader.add_css('elan_tarixi', 'div.product-statistics__i:nth-child(1) span.product-statistics__i-text::text')

        # Extract "Baxışların sayı: 193"
        loader.add_css('baxis_sayi', 'div.product-statistics__i:nth-child(2) span.product-statistics__i-text::text')

        # Processing to get the full "Dünən 12:54" part from the first value
        elan_tarixi_list = loader.get_output_value('elan_tarixi')
        elan_tarixi = elan_tarixi_list[0].split(":", 1)[1].strip() if elan_tarixi_list else ""
        loader.replace_value('elan_tarixi', elan_tarixi)

        loader.add_css('unvan', 'div.product-map__left__address::text')


        price_parts = response.css("div.product-price__i span::text").getall()
        full_price = " ".join(part.strip() for part in price_parts)
        loader.add_value('qiymet', full_price)

        kateqoriya_label=response.xpath("//div[@class='product-properties__i']/label/text()")[0].get()
        kateqoriya_span=response.css('div.product-properties__i span::text')[0].get()
        kateqoriya = f"{kateqoriya_label}:{kateqoriya_span}"
        loader.add_value('kateqoriya', kateqoriya)

        baxis_value = response.css('span.product-statistics__i-text::text')[1].get()[16:]
        loader.add_value('baxis_sayi', baxis_value)




        try:
            name1_label = response.xpath("//div[@class='product-properties__i']/label/text()")[1].get()
            name1_span = response.css('div.product-properties__i span::text')[1].get().strip()
            name1_value = f"{name1_label}:{name1_span}"
        except:
            name1_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('name1', name1_value)

        try:
            name2_label=response.xpath("//div[@class='product-properties__i']/label/text()")[2].get().strip()
            name2_span=response.css('div.product-properties__i span::text')[2].get().strip()
            name2_value = f"{name2_label}:{name2_span}"
        except:
            name2_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('name2', name2_value)

        try:
            name3_label = response.xpath("//div[@class='product-properties__i']/label/text()")[3].get()
            name3_span = response.css('div.product-properties__i span::text')[3].get().strip()
            name3_value = f"{name3_label}:{name3_span}"
        except:
            name3_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('name3', name3_value)

        try:
            name4_label = response.xpath("//div[@class='product-properties__i']/label/text()")[4].get()
            name4_span = response.css('div.product-properties__i span::text')[4].get().strip()
            name4_value = f"{name4_label}:{name4_span}"
        except:
            name4_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('name4', name4_value)

        try:
            name5_label = response.xpath("//div[@class='product-properties__i']/label/text()")[5].get()
            name5_span = response.css('div.product-properties__i span::text')[5].get().strip()
            name5_value = f"{name5_label}:{name5_span}"
        except:
            name5_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('name5', name5_value)

        try:
            name6_label = response.xpath("//div[@class='product-properties__i']/label/text()")[6].get()
            name6_span = response.css('div.product-properties__i span::text')[6].get().strip()
            name6_value = f"{name6_label}:{name6_span}"
        except:
            name6_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('name6', name6_value)

        try:
            name7_label = response.xpath("//div[@class='product-properties__i']/label/text()")[7].get()
            name7_span = response.css('div.product-properties__i span::text')[7].get().strip()
            name7_value = f"{name7_label}:{name7_span}"
        except:
            name7_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('name7', name7_value)

        try:
            name8_label = response.xpath("//div[@class='product-properties__i']/label/text()")[8].get()
            name8_span = response.css('div.product-properties__i span::text')[8].get().strip()
            name8_value = f"{name8_label}:{name8_span}"
        except:
            name8_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('name8', name8_value)


        try:
            owner_span = response.css('div.product-owner__info-region::text').get().strip()
            owner_value = f"{owner_span}"
        except:
            owner_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('owner', owner_value)        


        try:
            description = response.css('div.product-description-container div.product-description__content p::text').getall()
            description_value = " ".join(part.strip() for part in description)
        except:
            description_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('description', description_value)


        try:
            etraf_erazi_1_value=response.xpath("//li[@class='product-extras__i']/a/text()")[0].get()
        except:
            etraf_erazi_1_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('etraf_erazi_1', etraf_erazi_1_value)
        try:
            etraf_erazi_2_value=response.xpath("//li[@class='product-extras__i']/a/text()")[1].get()
        except:
            etraf_erazi_2_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('etraf_erazi_2', etraf_erazi_2_value)
        try:
            etraf_erazi_3_value=response.xpath("//li[@class='product-extras__i']/a/text()")[2].get()
        except:
            etraf_erazi_3_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('etraf_erazi_3', etraf_erazi_3_value)
        try:
            latitude_value= response.xpath("//div[@id='item_map']/@data-lat").get()
        except:
            latitude_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('latitude', latitude_value)
        try:
            longitude_value= response.xpath("//div[@id='item_map']/@data-lng").get()
        except:
            longitude_value = '' 
        loader.add_value('longitude', longitude_value)

        try:
            webpage_link = response.url
        except:
            webpage_link = ''
        loader.add_value('webpage_link', webpage_link)
        #try:
        #    description_value=' '.join(response.xpath("//div[@class='product-description__content']/p/text()").getall())
       # except:
            #description_value = '' 
       

        # Scraping image information
        image_urls = response.css('img[data-stat="product-gallery-item"]::attr(src)').getall()
        background_image_urls = response.css('span.product-photos__slider-top-i_background::attr(style)').getall()
        background_image_urls = [
            url.split("url('")[-1].split("')")[0] for url in background_image_urls
        ]
        image_urls.extend(background_image_urls)

        for i, img_url in enumerate(image_urls, start=1):
            image_name = f"{response.url.split('/')[-1]}_{i}.jpg"
            loader.add_value('image_urls', img_url)
            loader.add_value('image_names', image_name)
        

        #evler_item.add_value('description', description_value)
        today_date = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        loader.add_value('updated', today_date) 

        yield loader.load_item()

Pipelines code
# pipelines.py
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
import scrapy

class CustomImagePipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        # Extract the custom name from the request meta
        image_name = request.meta['image_name']
        return f'{image_name}'  # Save images with custom names

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        # Loop through the images and names
        for img_url, img_name in zip(item.get('image_urls', []), item.get('image_names', [])):
            yield scrapy.Request(img_url, meta={'image_name': img_name})  # Pass the custom name in meta

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        # Delete the image_names and image_urls after downloading
        if 'image_urls' in item:
            del item['image_urls']
        if 'image_names' in item:
            del item['image_names']
        
        # Return the item after removing image fields
        return item

#Settings
# Scrapy settings for bookscraper project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings by consulting the documentation:
# https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

BOT_NAME = "bookscraper"

SPIDER_MODULES = ["bookscraper.spiders"]
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = "bookscraper.spiders"

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1.5

# Configure item pipelines
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'bookscraper.pipelines.CustomImagePipeline': 300,  # Custom pipeline for images
}

# Set the directory for images
IMAGES_STORE = r'Deliberately revmoved'  # Adjust to your actual path

# Export settings to save scraped data in CSV format
FEED_FORMAT = "csv"
FEED_URI = r'Deliberately removed'  # Adjust the path to where you want the CSV to be saved

# Set settings for Scrapy pipelines and requests
REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = "2.7"
TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = "utf-8"

# Optional settings (if needed)
# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
# SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#     'bookscraper.middlewares.BookscraperSpiderMiddleware': 543,
# }

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
# EXTENSIONS = {
#     'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
# }

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
# AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0


What do you mean with "one attempt"?

Also, we can't adjust code that we don't see

@JamesZ Sorry. I adjusted the text

I set delay 1.5 seconds. Text is scraped in one attempt from one listing then waits 1.5 seconds and goes to the next listing. When I run the joint code with images, again, it scrapes all text information in one attempt, but for images, it scrapes 1st image in the first promotion listing, then waits 1.5 seconds, then scrapes 2nd images in the same listing,the third, 4th. There are 15-20 images in one listing, So, it takes 30-60 seconds to complete the first listing and step into the next listing. I want to scrape all pictures in one listing at one attempt, like it scrapes for text information.

DOWNLOAD_DELAY applies to all requests. And you seem to be using the word "attempt" incorrectly and/or thinking that images don't require a separate request for each of them.

Is there any way to download all images from one listing at once?

Depends on your idea of "at once".
